# Error: [LWC error]: Invalid url value "". Expected a non-empty string

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, summer19

### Error

[image: [LWC error]Invalid Url value ""]

### Details

I keep seeing this error in my Developer Console each time I load a page or a Lighting Component in my Lighting App. Please note there are no LWC components in the app. I see my scratch org is a new Summer 19 org, it's possible something in my code is causing this or it's a problem that started with the new API release.

### Code

I apologize, but I don't believe posting code will be helpful as I can't pinpoint which Custom Lighting Component (if any), of the very large code base, is causing the issue.

### Question

What, generally, can be the cause of this type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same issue on a lightning:carousel image and the problem turned out to be because I hadn't filled in the "href" parameter on the component (even though it wasn't required)

[image: Error being received]

Once I added in a random url into the href attribute (mentioned in the documentation), the issue went away:

[image: With href attribute filled in]

Does the documentation for any of your components include an href attribute? I think there's a bug in their component code which isn't handling attributes which haven't been included.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I think when I was using the chrome debugger something about href came up. My error mentions lightning-primitive-icon and none of the icon components have an href attribute. You're probably right that this is most likely a bug.